# How to hide time standards from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, datetime

I want to display only Day, Date, Time.
Now it displays:

[image]

Actually I want to display like:

[image]

How to remove --- "(India Standard Time)"

Used code below:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>(Type a title for your page here)</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function display_c() {
      var refresh = 1000; // Refresh rate in milli seconds
      mytime = setTimeout('display_ct()', refresh)
    }

    function display_ct() {
      var strcount
      var x = new Date()
      document.getElementById('ct').innerHTML = x;
      tt = display_c();
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body onload=display_ct();>
  <span id='ct'></span>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: https://momentjs.com/

Comment: downlod moment.js from momenttjs.com and then include

Comment: moment().format(LLLL);

Comment: Thanks guys, but i don't need any external js..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with some **Regex** pattern  `/GMT(.*)/g`  **[`.toString()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tostring_number.asp)** used to convert as a string for replace `GMT` and after all.

```js
function display_c() {
      var refresh = 1000; // Refresh rate in milli seconds
      mytime = setTimeout('display_ct()', refresh)
    }

    function display_ct() {
      var strcount
      var x = new Date()
      document.getElementById('ct').innerHTML = x.toString().replace(/GMT(.*)/g,"");
      tt = display_c();
    }
display_ct()
```

```html
  <span id='ct'></span>
```

Comment: welcome @Vishnu .If there  helpfull Don't forget to mark as a answer..Happy coding..!

Comment: Ok.. one more, is it possible to remove "onload=display_ct();"  from <body> tag

Comment: @Vishnu yes ... remove the  onload and directly paste function in js `display_ct()` its same like before.see my edited answer

Answer (score 1):

Another thing you can do is to use javascript's [**`toLocaleString()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) method for more *flexibility*-

1. It has options to format the string that you can specify - for instance in the demo below I'm using:

   ```
   var options = { weekday: 'short', year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: 'numeric', hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', second: 'numeric', hour12: false};
   ```
2. Now you can display the date string using this:

   ```
   document.getElementById('ct').innerHTML = x.toLocaleString('en-US', options);
   ```

See demo below:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>(Type a title for your page here)</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var options = { weekday: 'short', year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: 'numeric', hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', second: 'numeric', hour12: false};
    function display_c() {
      var refresh = 1000; // Refresh rate in milli seconds
      mytime = setTimeout('display_ct()', refresh)
    }

    function display_ct() {
      var strcount;
      var x = new Date();
      document.getElementById('ct').innerHTML = x.toLocaleString('en-US', options);
      tt = display_c();
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body onload=display_ct();>
  <span id='ct'></span>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @kukkuz :)