# Change the js time format from 24hr to 12hr

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have already asked a quesion [How to hide time standards from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42129661/6191987)

but i need to change time format to 12 hr.

```js
function display_c() {
      var refresh = 1000; // Refresh rate in milli seconds
      mytime = setTimeout('display_ct()', refresh)
    }

    function display_ct() {
      var strcount
      var x = new Date()
      document.getElementById('ct').innerHTML = x.toString().replace(/GMT(.*)/g,"");
      tt = display_c();
    }
display_ct()
```

```html
<span id='ct'></span>
```

Comment: [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you display javascript datetime in 12 hour AM/PM format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888491/how-do-you-display-javascript-datetime-in-12-hour-am-pm-format)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Match the `hours` with regex pattern `/(\d+)(:)/` and check `> 12` Then apply the condition.

**[Date methods](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp)**

```js
function display_c() {
  var refresh = 1000; // Refresh rate in milli seconds
  mytime = setTimeout('display_ct()', refresh)
}
var format;

function display_ct() {
  var strcount
  var x = new Date()
  document.getElementById('ct').innerHTML = x.toString().replace(/GMT(.*)/g, "").replace(/(\d+)(:)/,
    function(a, b, c) {
      b = parseInt(b);
      if (b > 12) {
        b = b - 12;
        format ='PM';
      }
    else{
      b=b;
    format="AM";
      }
      return b + c;
    })+format;
  tt = display_c();
}
display_ct()
```

```html
<span id='ct'></span>
```

**Or try with another model**

```js
function display_c() {
      var refresh = 1000; // Refresh rate in milli seconds
      mytime = setTimeout('display_ct()', refresh)
    }
var m =['Jan','Feb','Mar','Aprl','May','Jun','July','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
var w =['Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat'];

    function display_ct() {
      var strcount
      var x = new Date()
      var h = x.getHours() > 12 ? x.getHours() -12 : x.getHours();
      var format = x.getHours() > 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
      document.getElementById('ct').innerHTML =w[x.getDay()]+' '+m[x.getMonth()]+' '+x.getFullYear()+' '+h+':'+x.getMinutes()+':'+x.getSeconds()+' '+format;
      tt = display_c();
    }
display_ct()
```

```html
<span id='ct'></span>
```

Comment: Hi @prasad... is it possible to add AM, PM?

Comment: which one is better to choose - Regex or Array?

Comment: simple show up use with regex model.. if need apply some  action use the array model. because its  get individual data of the `date ,time second's,month,year`

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) string format. Using this you can display the date in the way you like.

In the below snippet you can see how to achieve same functionality.

```js
function display_c() {
  var refresh = 1000; // Refresh rate in milli seconds
  mytime = setTimeout('display_ct()', refresh)
}

function display_ct() {
  var strcount
  var x = new Date()
  document.getElementById('ct').innerHTML = moment(x).format('ddd MMM DD gggg hh:mm:ss');
  tt = display_c();
}

display_ct()
```

```html
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<span id='ct'></span>
```

**Note:**

1. `hh` is for **12 hours** [format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/), you can find more formats accesing the documentation (you can see some that I used in my example).
2. The nice thing about this is that remove the need of using `replace`.
3. And it follows the [KISS principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)

Comment: Thanks, it is very useful.. but no need any external js. only want to edit with the same code